# Is there any way to combine the functionality of LIKE and BETWEEN in a query?

Tags: sql-server

Im working on a query where the most obvious solution would be to combine the functionality of Like and Between, but im not sure if its possible.

My goal is to get ID's between a certain range, where the IDs are constructed of a leading code, followed by datetime, and the possible a couple more caracters like so:

ABC180715051623XYZ

The range would be from the current time, to 10 minutes prior. the leading characters don't matter for what is chosen, just the date time numbers in the center. an additional issue is that these leading characters can vary in length, somtimes 2, and other times 4.

On thatnote, ive been trying to use wildcards, and the like function, but they dont work as needed on there own. Is there any way to combine them?

Thank You

Comment: post sample data and desired result

Comment: Are the leading characters always letters?

Comment: for the input: 'ABC180715051623XYZ' can you give leading code, Datetime and other separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. The leading ID characters are always letters (actually just not numbers)
2. The date is always in the format `yyMMddhhmmss`

Then you could have your query as such:

```
 SELECT * FROM [your_table]
 WHERE CONVERT(                                   -- Converts to a datetime
         DATETIME, STUFF(                         -- STUFF #1
                   STUFF(                         -- STUFF #2
                   STUFF(                         -- STUFF #3
           SUBSTRING([id_column],                    
              PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[id_column]),    -- gets the index of the first number
               12),                               -- gets the 12 digit date string (SUBSTRING)
               7, 0, ' '),                        -- adds a space between date and time portions (STUFF #3)
               10, 0,  ':'),                      -- adds a ':' between hours and minutes (STUFF #2)
               13, 0, ':'))                       -- adds a ':' between minutes and seconds (STUFF #1)
 BETWEEN DATEADD(minute,-10, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)   -- 10 minutes ago
 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;                           -- now
```

This is taking the date and time part of the ID and forming it into a string that can then be converted into a `datetime` which can then be used in a the between of 10 mins ago and now. I've tried to format it so that it can be read but I'll explain the parts from the inside out below so you can edit if required.

Using your given value for ID of

> ABC180715051623XYZ

First `PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[id_column])` This gets the (1-based) index first number in the id column. So this would be `4`

This makes `SUBSTRING([id_column], 4, 12)` which gets out `180715051623`

So then `STUFF('180715051623', 7, 0, ' ')` puts a space at the 7th index, giving `180715 051623`

Then `STUFF('180715 051623', 10, 0, ':')` puts a ':' at the 10th index, giving `180715 05:1623`

Then `STUFF('180715 05:1623', 13, 0, ':')` puts a ':' at the 13th index, giving `180715 05:16:23`

This is then converted into the date '2018-07-15 05:16:23.000' and then used in the the between clause of two other datetimes.

Comment: Yes this looks perfect, and you assumed correct, sorry that I didn't clarify.